# Install *.deb file with "apt install"

Tags: ubuntu, apt, dpkg

What's the difference between installing a *.deb file with dpkg vs. apt?

I've been installing *.deb packages that I download (like Zoom) using "sudo apt install ./zoom-file.deb". It seems to work since I'm using Zoom and am not experiencing problems, but is there a difference if I "sudo dpkg -i ./zoom-file.deb" instead?

thx

Comment: Really there isn't a whole lot of difference in the initial installation between `dpkg` and `apt`.  BUT instead of you manually downloading and verifying your application, `apt` downloads the app from a **trusted repository** and does the install commands for you.  It's just a trustworthy, more convenient way to not only install your applications, but upgrade, and update them as well.  Think of it like this -- Manual installation vs "installation manager".

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question a few months ago. I'll link some articles at the end.

> "The apt-get uses dpkg for the actual package installation."
>
> "APT stands for Advanced Packaging Tools used in Debian and its
> derivatives to manage packages. It is used for installing, upgrading,
> configuring, removing packages, and maintaining source repositories.
>
> DPKG (Debian Package Manager) works under the hood of APT. While APT
> manages remote repositories and resolves dependencies for you, it uses
> dpkg to actually make the changes of installing/removing packages.
> dpkg on itself cannot retrieve/download files from remote
> repositories, nor can it figure out dependencies."

As you can conclude, APT delegates to DPKG.

You can find more info here

- https://www.linuxfordevices.com/tutorials/debian/apt-vs-dpkg-debian
- https://www.bogotobogo.com/Linux/linux-Package-Management-System-Ubuntu-apt-get-vs-dpkg.php

Hope this helps.

Comment: Btw, I think this question should be in https://askubuntu.com/ or https://superuser.com/